# NLog formatting as JSON using BeginScope

Tags: nlog, seq-logging

How do you get NLog to format data as JSON when using `ILogger.BeginScope`? It appears the the `@` symbol is ignored, or just not coded to work with begin scope? ref [documentation](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging)

I've tried every combination I can think of and they all result in the object being `ToString`'d rather than converted to JSON. The end result is that the data is not searchable as "structured" data because it's just a string.

**1st Attempt:**

```
using (_logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    ["CacheValue"] = value
}))
{
    _logger.LogInfo("howdy");
}
```

**Result in Seq:**

```
howdy
CacheValue MyApp.ViewModels.EntityIssueQueueGetModel
```

**2nd Attempt:**

```
using (_logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    ["@CacheValue"] = value
}))
{
    _logger.LogInfo("howdy");
}
```

**Result in Seq:**

```
howdy
@CacheValue MyApp.ViewModels.EntityIssueQueueGetModel
```

**3rd Attempt:**

```
using (_logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    ["{@CacheValue}"] = value
}))
{
    _logger.LogInfo("howdy");
}
```

**Result in Seq:**

```
howdy
{@CacheValue} MyApp.ViewModels.EntityIssueQueueGetModel
```

**4th Attempt:**

```
using (_logger.BeginScope("{@CacheValue}", value))
{
    _logger.LogInfo("howdy");
}
```

**Result in Seq:**

```
howdy
@CacheValue MyApp.ViewModels.EntityIssueQueueGetModel
```

---

This next bit works, but is not what I need. This prints the JSON out along with the friendly message. I only want the JSON data to be associated with the log for querying purposes; not shown as part of the message.

**Working example:**

```
_logger.LogInfo("howdy. {@CacheValue}", value);
```

**Result in Seq:**

```
howdy. {"Issues":[],"TotalRecords":0,"Success":true,"TraceId":"00-3b8ef0c2d84714e0c81a07cbb5d50444-8269922e21923478-00","Errors":[]}
CacheValue {
  "Issues": [],
  "TotalRecords": 0,
  "Success": true,
  "TraceId": "00-3b8ef0c2d84714e0c81a07cbb5d50444-8269922e21923478-00",
  "Errors": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NLog doesn't recognize message-template-syntax for Scope-Context-Properties.

NLog JsonLayout can format Scope-context Properties like this:

```
  <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeScopeProperties="true" maxRecursionLimit="1">
  </layout>
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/JsonLayout

It is also possible to format a single Scope-context Property as Json like this:

```
  layout="${scopeproperty:CacheValue:format=@}"
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ScopeProperty-Layout-Renderer

It is also possible to format the entire Scope-Nested-Stack as Json like this:

```
  layout="${scopenested:format=@}"
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ScopeNested-Layout-Renderer

Maybe consider posting your question at https://github.com/datalust/nlog-targets-seq